# How to hide Documents and Data for iOS app in iPhone Storage

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, local-storage

does anyone know how I can hide the documents and data for my iOS app in iPhone Storage? I see none of the apps in AppStore showing it but somehow my app is showing it to the user.
To view this screen, go to Settings > General > iPhone Storage > select the app.

**This is my App:**
[image: This is my iOS App]

**This is other App:**
[image: FB app]

Comment: How exactly did you store these documents within your app? That might be relevant.

Comment: Hi @Björn, I am using a third party library Database "Realm" to store the app data. But these documents is not something I stored in Realm :( It just some random icon and sometimes an encrypted file generated after using the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the key `UIFileSharingEnabled` from your info.plist file.